# Access files in docker container created during CI image build from host system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx

How can I access from the host system files placed during image build inside a docker container?

We build our docker images through the Gitlab CI/CG pipeline. During the build files like 404 pages, etc are placed in a folder at '/app/public/'. On our production server nginx is running on the host system and need to access this file.

When using the docker bind mount to mount a folder from the host system `/srv/web/public/:/app/public` into the container the content inside the folder `/app/public` is not accessible anymore.

At the moment we copy this hidden files via ansible to `/srv/web/public/` but this is such an ugly workaround.

```
version: '2'                                                                                                                                                                                          
services:                                                                                                                                                                                             
  web:                                                                                                                                                                                                
    image: registry.gitlab.com/project_web/web/master:latest                                                                                                                                  
    container_name: web                                                                                                                                                                               
    command: bundle exec rails s                                                                                                                                                                      
    entrypoint: /web/rails-entrypoint.sh                                                                                                                                                              
    volumes:                                                                                                                                                                                          
      - /srv/web/public/:/web/public                                                                                                                                                                  
      - /srv/web/log/:/web/log                                                                                                                                                                        
    env_file: .env                                                                                                                                                                                    
    ports:                                                                                                                                                                                            
      - '127.0.0.1:3333:3000'
```